# I had my first quetion locked before I got an answer

Tags: discussion

I was told it was in the wrong area on the site. It should have been in technology. I don't know how it ended up where it was and I can't find technology. You might have guessed, I'm not very computer savvy. I did find an answer to that question I posted. I wanted to share it with the site, but my question was locked, so I am here instead. I have to post a tag. Is that what places the post. I'm going to use piano. If it is what places the post, it will probably be locked again.

Comment: "Should have been in technology?" I'm not sure what that means or where that is from... that wasn't mentioned. And while you should use a relevant tag that is not what makes a question valid. Please read the [about] and [ask] pages as you were asked to do - they explain a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Hello and welcome to music.stackexchange! This site has [these rules](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about what questions can and can't be asked. The rules exist to preserve very specific goals of the site. The rules are designed to avoid things like:

- subjective arguments with no objective answer about things like which theory book is best
- obscure posts about specific songs that drive traffic away because they are not useful to others
- links to that are subject to rot, as is seen on the site a lot (especially with YouTube videos for tutorials)

Questions seeking this sort of content tend to shift the conversation away from the site's overarching goal: discussing and sharing the body of knowledge that makes up music performance, theory, and creation. In your case, you've requested off-site links that format the scales and fingerings in a printable form. It's not clear, for example, whether or not you already know all of the scales and fingerings and simply seek the information formatted for printing. This sort of request would be off topic and outside the goals of the site.

There is a way to rephrase your question so that it is "on topic" and fits within the specific rules of this site, but it may not be useful to you given your desire for something printable. In particular, here's how you can ask this question:

> What are the notes in the major blues scale and what are the notes in the minor blues scale? What are the fingerings for these scales, in each of the 12 keys?

Hope this helps and clears things up!

Comment: You did help. Thank you.